# How do you split a Django queryset without evaluating it?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

I am dealing with a **Queryset of over 5 million + items** (For batch ML purposes) and I need to **split the queryset** (so I can perform multithreading operations) **without evaluating the queryset** as I only ever need to access each item in the queryset once and thus I don't want to cache the queryset items which evaluating causes.

Is it possible to select the items into one queryset and split this without evaluating? or am I going to have to approach it by querying for multiple querysets using Limits [:size] to achieve this behaviour?

**N.B:** I am aware that an Iterable can be used to cycle through a queryset without evaluating it but my question is related to how I can I split a queryset (if possible) to then run an iterable on each of the splitted querysets.

Comment: Could you iterate over it and let the worker threads fetch work? That’s the only way I can imagine it working with a single query through Django. (Pretty much just passing a threadsafe iterator around.)

Comment: A django query is not evaluated until it hits something forcing evaluation.  And it can be sliced.   So myQuery[1000: 11000] would very cleanly give you a part of the query.  And no, it doesn't evaluate the entire thing to get that slice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django provides a few classes that help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links:

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

object_list = MyModel.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 10) # Show 10 objects per page, you can choose any other value

for i in paginator.page_range(): # A 1-based range iterator of page numbers, e.g. yielding [1, 2, 3, 4].
    data = iter(paginator.get_page(i))
    # use data
```

Comment: I believe for my problem the paginator seems like the best solution, cheers for the help! N.B.: for anyone reading the items of a page are not evaluated until requested i.e. lazy evalaution

Comment: For Django 3.0 page_range is not callable anymore, it's just a property. And .get_page(i) => .page(i)

Comment: @jTiKey i have tried this in django 1.7 and it's not callable, it's just a list. i belive this is a mistake

Answer (score 8):

If your django version is **1.11** or less than that like **1.10**, **1.9** or so on, then use [paginator.page(page_no)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/paginator/#Paginator.page) but be careful that this may raise an InvalidPage Exception when invalid/no page has been found.

For versions **<= 1.11**, use below code:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

qs = MyModel.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(qs, 20)

for page_no in paginator.page_range:
    current_page = paginator.page(page_no)
    current_qs = current_page.object_list
```

And if you're using django version >= 2.0, please use [paginator.get_page(page_no)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_page) instead, but you can also use [paginator.page(page_no)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/paginator/#Paginator.page).

For versions >= 2.0, use below code:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

qs = MyModel.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(qs, 20)

for page_no in paginator.page_range:
    current_page = paginator.get_page(page_no)
    current_qs = current_page.object_list
```

The advantage of using [paginator.get_page(page_no)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_page) according to django documentations is as follows:

> Return a valid page, even if the page argument isn't a number or isn't
>           in range.

While in the case of [paginator.page(page_no)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/paginator/#Paginator.page), you have to handle the exception manually if page_no is not a number or is out of range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 3):

Passing query sets to Threads is not something I would recommend. I know the sort of thing you are trying to do and why, but its best to just pass some sort of param set to each thread and then have the Thread perform the partial query.
Working this way, your threads are distinct from the calling code.

On a different note, if you are trying to use threads as a work around for the lags caused by high DB queries, you might find using transaction management a better route.
This link [link](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785) has some useful tips. I use this instead of Threads

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/syrusakbary/7982653#gistcomment-2038879)

Per the updated answer:

```
def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunk_size=1000):
"""
Iterate over a Django Queryset ordered by the primary key
This method loads a maximum of chunk_size (default: 1000) rows in it's
memory at the same time while django normally would load all rows in it's
memory. Using the iterator() method only causes it to not preload all the
classes.
Note that the implementation of the iterator does not support ordered query sets.
"""
    try:
        last_pk = queryset.order_by('-pk')[:1].get().pk
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return

    pk = 0
    queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')
    while pk < last_pk:
        for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunk_size]:
            pk = row.pk
            yield row
        gc.collect()
```